# how to call rest api in Apex Class

Tags: apex, rest-api

I'd like to use salesforce rest api in Apex Controller class.
Main purpose to use rest api in Apex is to fetch listview colums details(colums order and colums field name) and output visualforce page with xlsx format in visualforce. when I try this sample code in Visualforce using fetch api, it works fine, but in Apex class, it fails.
Error Message is shown.
FATAL_ERROR System.CalloutException: no protocol: Url:[delegate=https://cs75.salesforce.com]/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account/listviews/00B5F0000059jK4UAI/describe

anybody konows how to solve it?
thanks for advance.

Sample code is as below.

```
public class ListViewSampleController {
    public Id listviewId {get; set;}

    public ListViewSampleController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.listviewId = [SELECT Id FROM ListView WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND DeveloperName = 'ALL'].Id;
        fetchListViewDetail();
        
    }
    
    public void fetchListViewDetail() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        
        req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl() + '/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account/listviews/' + this.listviewId + '/describe');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: I found a solution. This code works well**

change like below

```
req.setEndpoint(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account/listviews/' + this.listviewId + '/describe');
```

Comment: if its working fine with you add it as a solution and accept it as an answer.

Comment: thank you. I add my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution. you don't need a remote site setting when you use 'URL.getOrgDomainUrl'
instead of 'URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl'.

```
req.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account/listviews/' + this.listviewId + '/describe');
```